# Why getElementbyId not working in this case?

Tags: javascript, html

Okay So this is the code. When I run it. It just has the `h1` tag and 3 subparts. It doesn't take value from `getElementByID` function and assigns it to respective id.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Playlsit</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
    function addsongs() {
      var song1 = document.getElementById('song1');
      var song2 = document.getElementById('song2');
      var song3 = document.getElementById('song3');

      song1.innerHTML = "Blue Suede Strings, By Elvis Pagely";
      song2.innerHTML = "Great Objects on Fire, by Jerry JSON Lewis";
      song3.innerHTML =  "I code the Line,by Johnny Javascripts"
    }    
    window.onload = "addsongs";
  </script>    
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My awesome Playlist</h1>
  <ul id="playlist">
    <li id = "song1"</li>
    <li id= "song2"</li>
    <li id = "song3"</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: close li tags also

Comment: Remove the quotes from `window.onload = "addsongs"` - currently your function won't even be called.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Yes for that reason I am using window.onload function. So the fuction works once the page is already loaded.

Comment: do some html correction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have missed the `>` symbol of starting li element.

Also function cannot be assigned as string value. Remove the quotes.

```
window.onload = addsongs;
```